# Exclude a specific range of time in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I have a stored procedure that queries my database to pull a "Open" report for "Yesterdays" date.  This program will run on windows scheduler always querying the database for yesterdays results.  I want all of the results from yesterday EXCEPT 5:30AM - 6:26AM.  I do not care to see these results... Everything works, with the exception of not displaying the specified time block...

My stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Open_Close] AS
declare   @dtNow         datetime ,   @dtToday       datetime ,   @dtFrom        datetime ,   @dtThru        datetime ,   @dtExcludeFrom datetime ,   @dtExcludeThru datetime  
set @dtNow         = getdate() 
set @dtToday       = convert(datetime,convert(varchar,@dtNow,112),112) 
set @dtFrom        = dateadd(day,-1,@dtToday) -- start-of-day yesterday 
set @dtThru        = dateadd(ms,-3,@dtToday)  -- end-of-day yesterday (e.g., 2012-06-17 23:59:59.997) 
set @dtExcludeFrom = convert(datetime, convert(char(10),@dtFrom,120) + ' 05:30:00.000' , 120 ) 
set @dtExcludeThru = convert(datetime, convert(char(10),@dtFrom,120) + ' 06:15:00.000' , 120 )  

SELECT Store_Id , DM_Corp_Received_Date
FROM Register_Till_Count_Tb 
WHERE Register_Transaction_Type    =  'SOD'   
AND Register_Till_Count_Datetime     between @dtFrom        
and @dtThru  AND Register_Till_Count_Datetime not between @dtExcludeFrom 
and @dtExcludeThru
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem.  The dates are being calculated correctly and the WHERE clause is set up to do what you intend.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
Register_Till_Count_Datetime not between @dtExcludeFrom and @dtExcludeThru
```

to

```
 (Register_Till_Count_Datetime < @dtExcludeFrom  OR 
  Register_Till_Count_Datetime > @dtExcludeThru)
```

Don't forget the parentheses.

The `NOT BETWEEN` doesn't always work as you would expect.

Comment: This also returns the same results.

Comment: @Shmewnix, What does the Register_Till_Count_Datetime result look like.  Also, confirm its data type.

Comment: `1 2012-08-08 05:05:16.8 2 2012-08-08 06:03:57.7`  it's DATETIME

Comment: @Shmewnix, I'm not sure what's going on. As Gordon Linoff stated, the query looks correct.  I checked your @ variables and they look correct. My last stab at this is to replace the entire date check in the where clause with: 
`AND (Register_Till_Count_Datetime >= @dtFrom AND Register_Till_Count_Datetime < @dtExcludeFrom)
OR (Register_Till_Count_Datetime > @dtExcludeThru AND Register_Till_Count_Datetime < @dtToday)`
(Basically, eliminate all the BETWEEN statements.)

Comment: Already Tried that... Did not work... Returns the same results... All 10 locations display the correct date. but for ALL times.

Comment: @Shmewnix, Any chance that DM_Corp_Received_Date is the date you should be looking at?  At any rate, I've tried to check the query six ways from Sunday and can't find anything that would cause your query to return the excluded records.

Comment: I was just commenting to tell you I was referencing the WRONG column... You caught it at the same time I did... I'm an idiot.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
AND NOT (Register_Till_Count_Datetime between @dtExcludeFrom and @dtExcludeThru )
```

Comment: This returns the same results.