# How to query for a specific date range excluding a specific time range

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datetime

I have a program that auto-run's with windows scheduler.  What the program does is runs a query for "Yesterdays" Results... it then filters the results not including anything in the specific time range.  The problem I have right now is I have to specify the date in the query... How can I have the query automatically exclude the time (between 5:30 am and 6:15 am)

```
SELECT  Store_Id, DM_Corp_Received_Date
FROM    Register_Till_Count_Tb
WHERE   (DM_Corp_Received_Date >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) 
    AND (Register_Transaction_Type = 'sod') 
    AND (DM_Corp_Received_Date < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) 
    AND (DM_Corp_Received_Date NOT BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '2012-08-08 05:30:00', 102) AND CONVERT(Datetime, '2012-08-08 06:15:00', 102))
```

Comment: This look suspiciously similar to your earlier post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886769/exclude-a-specific-range-of-time-in-a-stored-procedure/11887118#comment15819122_11887118 (except the you are now using DM_Corp_Received_Date instead of Register_Till_Count_Datetime.

Comment: @HolgerBrandt  You are correct.  This is and has been addressed.  I was initally thinking it was something in the stored procedure and was looking to go to a query instead of a Stored Procedure... I'm good to go.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Yesterday DATETIME = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0));
DECLARE @Today DATETIME = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0));

SELECT  Store_Id, DM_Corp_Received_Date
FROM    Register_Till_Count_Tb
WHERE   (DM_Corp_Received_Date >= @Yesterday
    AND (Register_Transaction_Type = 'sod') 
    AND (DM_Corp_Received_Date < @Today
    AND (DM_Corp_Received_Date NOT BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, 5*60+30, @Yesterday) AND   
         DATEADD(minute, 6*60+15, @Yesterday))
```

Note that `BETWEEN` is inclusive so be careful around your boundaries.

Comment: Thanks, I added a clarification.

Comment: @Shmewnix . . . does this actually work?  It looks like a better way to reformulate the original query.  However, does it fix your problem?